# How can i add a unique identifier to the same value of specific key in php array

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [proomsize] => dasfdsfdsf
            [proomtype] => Bedroom
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [proomsize] => dasfdsfsd
            [proomtype] => Bedroom
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [proomsize] => dfadsf
            [proomtype] => KitchenDinner
        )   


    [4] => Array
        (
            [proomsize] => dafdsads
            [proomtype] => Reception
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [proomsize] => fdsafdsfdsf
            [proomtype] => Reception
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [proomsize] => adfadfdsf
            [proomtype] => Reception
        )
    )
```

Now i need is if there is more than one $array['proomtype'] of same value i want to append a number at the end in my foreach loop.. so when i loop through it i want a result like this

```
Bedroom 1 : dasfdsfdsf
Bedroom 2 : dasfdsfsd
KitchenDinner : dfadsf
Reception 1 : dasfdsfsd
Reception 2 : adfdsf
Reception 3 : dfdfdf
```

how can i achieve that in a single loop i have tried using this

```
<?php 
$BedroomCounter = 0;
if ($value['proomtype'] == 'Bedroom') {
    if ($BedroomCounter == 0) {
       echo $value['proomtype'] ':' .$value['proomsize'] . '<br>'; 
    }else{
        echo $value['proomtype'] . $BedroomCounter . ':' .$value['proomsize'] . '<br>'; 
    }

    $BedroomCounter++;
}
```

the issue is i have repeat this for each n every roomtype.. which is not something i want to.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: i did found the solution.. but for that i have write multiple if statements and multiple loops
if ($value['proomtype'] == 'Bedroom' && $BedroomCounter < 2) {
                        $BedroomCounter++; ?>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 information-label">
                            <?php
                                $RoomType[$value['proomtype']];
                                echo ' ' . $BedroomCounter; 
                        ?>

Comment: then show your code... will correct it

Comment: updated my question with solution code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this works is by first using [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to count the number of each type of room, this helps know when we need to add a suffix or not.
It then creates a copy of this array with the current counter for each room type starting at 1 using [`array_fill_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php).

The code then loops through all of the entries looking up the room type and if the room type has more than 1 entry it adds the suffix from the counter array and increments that counter.

```
$duplicates = array_count_values(array_column($value, "proomtype"));
$currentCount = array_fill_keys(array_keys($duplicates), 1);
foreach ( $value as $key=>$entry ){
    if ( $duplicates[$entry["proomtype"]] > 1 ) {
        $value[$key]["proomtype"] .= " ".$currentCount[$entry["proomtype"]];
        $currentCount[$entry["proomtype"]]++;
    }
}
print_r($value);
```

The output with your example data is...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [proomsize] => dasfdsfdsf
            [proomtype] => Bedroom 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [proomsize] => dasfdsfsd
            [proomtype] => Bedroom 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [proomsize] => dfadsf
            [proomtype] => KitchenDinner
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [proomsize] => dafdsads
            [proomtype] => Reception 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [proomsize] => fdsafdsfdsf
            [proomtype] => Reception 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [proomsize] => adfadfdsf
            [proomtype] => Reception 3
        )

)
```